# PHP associative array with two properties

Tags: php, array

I'm moving a system over to PDO and since the queries are parameterized, I need to specify both the type and value of each parameter when preparing them.

Right now I have a `prepare` method to create the `PDOStatement` object:

```
/**
 * Prepares a statement
 * @param string $sql The query
 * @param array $data The data to bind
 * @param array $types The types of data
 * @return \PDOStatement
 */
private function prepare($sql, array $data, array $types) {
    if (sizeof(array_diff_key($types, $data)) || sizeof(array_diff_key($data, $types))) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Keys of data and types arrays do not match.');
    }

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindValue($key, $value, $types[$key]);
    }
    return $stmt;
}
```

Places where the code is called look like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET col1 = :param1, col2 = :param2, col3 = :param3 WHERE primary_key = :id;";

$data = array('param1' => $param1, 'param2' => $param2, 'param3' => $param3, 'id' => $id);
$types = array('param1' => \PDO::PARAM_STR, 'param2' => \PDO::PARAM_STR, 'param3' => \PDO::PARAM_INT, 'id' => \PDO::PARAM_INT);

static::$db->prepare($sql, $data, $types)->execute();
```

**It feels a bit cumbersome to specify the data and types in two separate arrays. Is there any way I can improve this?**

I could make a SQLParameter class like this:

```
class SQLParameter {
    public $name;
    public $value;
    public $type;

    public function __construct($name, $value, $type) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->type = $type;
    }
}
```

But this would make the situation even worse.

Comment: Haven't worked that much with PDO stuff to be honest, but can't you just use the implicit conversion and pass everything quotes/as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can immediately see two more options, perhaps they're something you're after, perhaps not.

### Option 1

Turn `$data` into a multidimensional array. You would end up with something such as:

```
...array('param1' => [$param1, \PDO::PARAM_STR], 'param2' => [$param2, \PDO::PARAM_STR]...
```

**Pros**

- Both value data and type are paired to the key, so now you can simply refer to either with array referencing.
- You can play with indentations and returns to find a format that suits you. It's easy enough to separate each key/value onto a new line.

**Cons**

- It's more condensed, which might lead to readability issues. (Do you keep in mind the 2nd pro above though)
- An IDE's autoformat might place it all on one line, depending on your settings.

### Option 2

Have a type searching function to automatically determine the type and assign it. This could be a simple helper function with a few conditionals, each with one of the [`is_*` variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php).

You would want to call the function as a parameter of `bindValue()`.

**Pros**

- This would scale quite well.
- It's easy to alter outputs and fine-tune.
- You won't have to add the type every time you add a new key/value pair.
- Can even check for things such as objects and handle those properly.

**Cons**

- More business code and less model/data code.

---

I would agree that the `SQLParameter` is overboard. If anything, maybe one of my solutions will inspire your own.